# To get data of points plotted in different area of scatter plots in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have created a scatter plot for a fantasy league for different players between 'players cost' and 'fantasy points'. Now I want to get the  information (like Name,age,team,etc) of the data points on the left side of the green vertical line and more specifically at North-West part of the graph.
Is there any function "get" to get information the data points.

Image desription:
Normal scatter plot with two vertial lines  v1 at x=6 and v2 at x = 10. I want to get information of datapoints plotted on left of v1 from the plot

Following is the code i wrote to draw this scatter plot

```
x = dataset.loc[:,"Cost"]
y = datasetloc[:,"Points"]
plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
plt.scatter(x,y,size =100,marker = '*',color = 'b',alpha = 0.8,edgeolors 
= 'white')
plt.xlabel("Indiidual Players Cost")
plt.ylabel("Fantasy Points")
plt.title("Players Cost Vs Fantasy Points")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to access information directly from your dataset.

```
nw = dataset[(dataset.Cost <= 6) & (dataset.Points >= 0)]
ne = dataset[(dataset.Cost >= 6) & (dataset.Points >= 0)]
sw = dataset[(dataset.Cost <= 6) & (dataset.Points <= 0)]
se = dataset[(dataset.Cost >= 6) & (dataset.Points <= 0)]
```